# How to pass data to other scopes variables in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have controller

```
<div ng-controller="LeftSideNavWorkController as vm"  ">
  <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index">
    <div ng-click="vm.hideAllElements()>Hide</div>
    <div ng-show = "showChildren[$index]" >Show/Hide element<div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in controller:

```
vm.hideAllElements = hideAllElements;
vm.items = [... ... ...]; //some array of items

function hideAllElements() {
//how set all showChildren[] variables to false?
 }
```

the task is that when I click on one  it should set all vm.show  = false

Comment: `Close all repeated elements` - not clear with this? What exactly is the desired result? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: edited. The final task is to close all opened elements when I click on any of <div>Hide</div>

Comment: You need to elaborate what is close and open with an example, otherwise, it is difficult to judge the desired functionality you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS ONE:
HTML:

```
   <div ng-controller="LeftSideNavWorkController as vm"  ">
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index">
      <div ng-click="vm.hideAllElements()>Hide</div>
      <div ng-show = "showChildren[$index]" >Show/Hide element<div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CTRL:

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('appController', appController);
    // main.js
    function appController($scope, $interval) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        vm.hideAllElements = hideAllElements;
        vm.show = true;


        function hideAllElements() {
            vm.items.forEach(function(obj, i) {
                vm.show = false;
            });
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: where did you take app?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do

In your view

```
 <div ng-controller="LeftSideNavWorkController as vm"  ">
    <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items track by $index">
         <div ng-click="vm.hideAllElements()>Hide</div>
         <div ng-show = "item.show" >Show/Hide element<div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

In controller function:

```
function hideAllElements() {
    vm.items.forEach(function(item) {
       item.show = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited question. will not use vm.show any more .

Comment: @Serhiy as the controller level variable is shared inside view, you have to define property in each item to handle show/hide of item.